# Ant Media Server

Tags: filesize, ant-media-server-sdk

I am trying to broadcast a video file with music however it is taking too long to upload the VOD file for Ant Media Server

I tried separating the files into the video file and audio file which made the upload smoother. However, when I try to broadcast nothing happens since youtube doesnt detect the audio file. Is there a way to do this properly where it does both at the same time